# Create a String with a for loop and then use cURL to post

Tags: php, curl

Please help me out how can I make this working if it is th righ way to do it and if it not what would you suggest to post the parameters

```
$str = '';
for( $i = 11; $i <= 20; $i++ )
{
 $str .= $i . ' ';    
}
$ch = curl_init(); //http post to another server
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://xxxx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"username=$username&password=$password&string=$str"); 

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
print_r($server_output);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: What is the problem? What errors are you getting? What are you expecting?

Comment: Maybe the space is a problem?

Comment: Create the `CURL_POSTFIELDS` value in a string before hand then use `curl_escape` to encode it - the spaces will be a problem as @putvande suggested. Also, a hint as to the problem you're actually having would be useful

Comment: I dont really get any errors but I dont get any response from the http. I would like to know whether this code, as written, looks fine for the use i want it

Comment: You may want to use `urlencode()` on your `$str` after loop.

Comment: @Volvox, **Not neccessary**. It is being sent via `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the script you call with curl, try to add:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

and see what is printed.

I just made your code a bit better readable.
But its correct. Should works.

Try to have a look at the php_errors log file and see if it fires something.

```
<?php

$str = '';
for( $i = 11; $i <= 20; $i++ ) {
    $str .= $i . ' ';
}

$ch = curl_init(); //http post to another server
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL           , 'http://xxxx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST          , 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    , 'username=' . $username . '&password=' . $password . '&string=' . $str);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

print_r($server_output);

curl_close($ch);
```

@Stoic Passing an array in POSTFIELDS determine the Content-type header = multipart. Could alter the response.

Comment: When did `google.com` started accepting username and password ?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your code is correct, but you can use the following function as an helper:

```
<?php
$url  = "http://xxxx";
$str  = implode(" ", range(11,20));
$data = array("username" => $username, "password" => $password, "string" => $str);

$server_output = processURL($url, $data);
print_r($server_output);

function processURL($url, $data = array()){ 
    $ch=curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
    $response = curl_exec ($ch); 
    curl_close ($ch); 
    return $response; 
}
```

Note that, I do understand that using [`range`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) is a bit slower than the `for` loop, but I like it for its readability and cleaner code :)